# QT: Escape slash / in saving location on a mac

Tags: macos, qt, escaping

I have HTML input I am supposed to extract 2 Strings of, build a document title string of type `<string 1> / <string 2`, create a PDF from the source on the users mac desktop and name it as described.

I do know that a slash in a document name is not such a brilliant idea but this is what I am asked to do.

Problem is: the forward slash is interpreted as a folder on the mac and not as part of the documents name which means QPainter fails to print to PDF because it interpretes `string1 /` being a folder that doesn't exist.

BTW when omitting the `/` my code is working fine.

How am I supposed to escape the `/`?

Here's the string building logic:

```
QString docTitle;
docTitle.append(string1);
docTitle.append(" / ");
docTitle.append(string2);
```

Comment: `/` is part of the path I doubt you can use it in the file name. So I don't know what escape sequence you are trying to find - you can replace it with whatever character you wish but you can't use `/` in the file name.

Comment: Well obviously you are right in terms of file structure, but on a visual user level a filename can contain `/` . See Ken Thomases answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, the name of a file at the level of the APIs is different from the display name that is shown to the user in the Finder, open and save panels, etc.

At the level of the APIs, file names simply **can't** contain slashes. They are reserved for separating names within a path. There's no form of escaping or quoting to allow it.

However, you can create a file whose name will be *displayed* with a slash in the UI.

Basically, the slash (`/`) and colon (`:`) characters swap roles. The display names of files can't include a colon, because it's reserved. (This is a holdover of the old HFS file system used in Classic Mac OS.) So, one aspect of the conversion from names-in-the-APIs to display names is to convert from colons to slashes. Thus, if you want a file whose display name has a slash, you actually use a colon.

A file whose name as per the APIs is "Important legal document 06:13:2015.pdf" will be displayed in the UI as "Important legal document 06/13/2015.pdf". Likewise, if a user names a file in a save dialog or in the Finder as "Important legal document 06/13/2015.pdf", it will end up with a name which, when observed via the APIs, will be "Important legal document 06:13:2015.pdf".

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I've been looking for, sharply explained. Thank you.